# Default groups associated to a new local user (Windows 10.0.17763)

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, user, local-groups

I'm working on a standalone Windows 10.0.17763 (no AD)

```
C:\Windows\system32>systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise N
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
```

I'd like to know which (and where) is the policy that assigns default groups to a newly created "local user".

I'm using "net add" command as below.

```
c:\Windows\System32>net user theuser P@ssw0rd /add
The command completed successfully.
```

These are the default groups assigned to the user .

```
C:\Windows\system32>whoami /all

USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name             SID
===================== =============================================
win10n-devenv\theuser S-1-5-21-3355217364-1844382339-729736612-1002


GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------

Group Name                             Type             SID          Attributes
====================================== ================ ============ ==================================================
Everyone                               Well-known group S-1-1-0      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Users                          Alias            S-1-5-32-545 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Performance Log Users          Alias            S-1-5-32-559 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE               Well-known group S-1-5-4      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users       Well-known group S-1-5-11     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization         Well-known group S-1-5-15     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Local account             Well-known group S-1-5-113    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
LOCAL                                  Well-known group S-1-2-0      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication       Well-known group S-1-5-64-10  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level Label            S-1-16-8192
```

Weird! Where, for example, does "BUILTIN\Performance Log Users" come from?
From which configured policy?